# Error: ENOENT: no such file or directory, open '../config/credentials.json'

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

[Folder Image here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/q3MTx.png)How to fix this error with my Nodejs code i am using es6 imports and i am importing like this

```
import VoximplantApiClient from '@voximplant/apiclient-nodejs';
const client = new VoximplantApiClient.default('../config/credentials.json')
```

And the error is

```
/Users/sam/Desktop/Call-Nodejs/node_modules/@voximplant/apiclient-nodejs/dist/index.js:2349
                throw err;
                ^

[Error: ENOENT: no such file or directory, open '../config/credentials.json'] {
  errno: -2,
  code: 'ENOENT',
  syscall: 'open',
  path: '../config/credentials.json'
}
```

Node.js v20.1.0 I doubled check the path and the path is correct...

Comment: have you tried with an absolute path?

Comment: @Emilien Sorry but i don't understand what you mean by "absolute path" Can you please give an example for that?

Comment: Is this path relative to the current working directory or to the file? An absolute path doesn't start with `..` or `.`.

Comment: absolute path works fine but whats wrong with normal path

Comment: The relative path for `/Users/sam/Desktop/Call-Nodejs/config/credentials.json` from `/Users/sam/Desktop/Call-Nodejs` is `./config/credentials.json`. You shouldn't make assumptions like _"the path is correct"_.

Comment: so if i deploy my app to vercel then what will be the path?

Comment: The relative path is either relative to the current working directory (more common) or the file (less common). It depends on the file structure and how the app is started. More details are necessary to answer your question.

Comment: @jabaa please check my edited question and check the image

Comment: Your question still contains _"I doubled check the path and the path is correct"_, but obviously the path is wrong. Change the path. It looks like the folder `config` is in the folder `src`. I would change that. What is the working directory when you start the app?

Comment: @jabaa i am working in Desktop directory, but what will happen when i deploy my app on vercel?

Comment: The working directory is the folder where the process is started from. You have to know how the Node.js process is started on Vercel and adept the path accordingly.

Comment: @jabaa i created my project in desktop directory the project name is Call-Nodejs, i am on macos

Comment: You probably need either `./config/credentials.json` or `./src/config/credentials.json` but it is really unclear without the necessary details. If you don't know, how the process is started on Vercel, you need to find out the absolute path.

Comment: @jabaa i found this https://nextjs.org/docs/app/building-your-application/configuring/absolute-imports-and-module-aliases

Answer (score 0):

For path-related splicing in nodejs, it is recommended to use： [path.resolve](https://nodejs.org/dist/latest-v19.x/docs/api/path.html#pathresolvepaths)

```
const yoursPath = path.resolve('/foo/bar', '../config/credentials.json');
const client = new VoximplantApiClient.default(yoursPath)
```

Comment: it does require permission any other way? when i deploy to vercel